# javascript string manipulation

Tags: javascript, string

I would like to modify my strings so i can replace the character ' ' with '_' using JS,for example "new zeland"=>"new_zeland"
how can i do that?

Answer (score 8):

```
var str = 'new zealand';
str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '_');
```

Comment: +1 for fastest option according to these jsperf benchmarks - http://jsperf.com/split-join-vs-replace/2

Answer (score 1):

You could use Rob's code, but it uses a regular expression to find the space, while it would be faster to just search for a literal space:

```
var string = 'new zealand';
var newString = string.replace(' ', '_');
```

Comment: If you can be certain that there is always only **one** space.

Comment: Well, in `new zealand`, there is ;) And we don't know what the OP wants. He might want to replace every space by an underscore, so `new[3 spaces]zealand` would be `new___zealand`...